# android listview row name referred to class name, how to change it

Tags: android

My listview row appears with one word name. I want to change into two words. I can't because this list name referred to class name. Also I can't include space in class name so I don't know how to solve this.
example ( Day1) want to change to (day one).

#### (menu.class)

```
             public class Menu extends ListActivity {
   String classes[] = { "Introduction",  "Day1",  "Day2", "Day3", 
              "Day4", "Day5", "Day6", "Day7", "Day8", "Day9", "Day10", "Day11", 
              "Day12", "Day13", "Day14", "Day15", "Day16", "Day17", "Day18", "Day19",
         "Day20", "Day21", "Day22", "Day23", "Conclusion"};


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.row, R.id.label,
            classes));

    }


 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.menu" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
 }

  }

    }
```

#### (day .class)

```
          public class Day1 extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.day1);

        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
         "BFantezy.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(face);
          }
         }
```

Comment: I cannot understand your question clearly. Do you need your class to be named "Day one"?

Comment: thanks for reply when i run the app list view items appear as (Day1) then (Day2) , yes i want it to appear ( Day one ) , class to be named ( Day one ) , thats riht

Comment: Rename your class using Refactor. If you just want to change your class name.

Comment: Class name cannot contain space. You can create 1 parent class and extend it in each subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know what is common between your `day` classes, my solution to your problem is after modifying your classes array to what you want:

```
String classes[] = { "Introduction",  "Day one",  "Day Two", "Day three",  "Day four", ... , "Day twenty three", "Conclusion"};
```

a simple `if` check after that is used to modify the class name respectivly when you define the `intent`:

```
String cheese = classes[position]; 
if(cheese.equals("Day one")) cheese = "Day1";
if(cheese.equals("Day two")) cheese = "Day2";
if(cheese.equals("Day three")) cheese = "Day3";
//...Continure until day22
```

Comment: hi man i did as you told me but nothing changed still appear as( Day1 ) , ( Day2) ,

Comment: thanks alot man ,its run like a charm , you are my master thanks

Comment: Please accept my answer since it answered your initial question, I do not have an answer for your new question related to fonts yet, but if I come across it I will let you know

Comment: sorry regard acceptance first ques. im new to this amazing site , already accepted